# Why does my automated blueprism process not work anymore after I import it from my computer to another one?

Tags: process, automation, blueprism, rpa

On my computer the automated process works totally fine. I use dynamic attributes like "ID".
When I import the process and the corresponding VBO's blueprism is not able to detect these elements with dynamic ID's. Even after I spied new elments, it does not work.

On my computer I have blueprism installed in version 6.5.0.12573
On the other computer it is installed in version 6.4.2.10610

Comment: Can you provide exactly where the process fails? You mention ID, have you taken a snapshot in both machines to see what the underlying application elements look like?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your environment is different than the other one you want to import the process. You should consider and double check any configuration of all applications used by the process.
For example I had same problem about Mozilla Firefox browser driver version.

Comment: I've checked the Google Chrome Version on both computers. They are identical. But the BluePrism version differs. Nevertheless when I spy new elements on the remote computer, it is still not possible to highlight/ detect the elements.

Comment: @Kevin01 Are you using some Chrome Extension to work with BluePrism? here's the link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blue-prism-browser-extens/oaflhlmnamdgbgdgakpihkkdfapkebfp?hl=en-GB